# Can't change group of files on mount point

Tags: permissions, mount, group, ntfs

I have mounted some ntfs drives. `/etc/fstab` looks like this:

```
/dev/mapper/fedora-root /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=b6603ac8-e004-4cd6-b141-9bc95409e32a /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/fedora-home /home                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/fedora-swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
/dev/sda1       /mnt/media  ntfs-3g defaults 0 0
/dev/sda5       /mnt/setups ntfs-3g defaults 0 0
/dev/sda6       /mnt/documents  ntfs-3g defaults 0 0
```

I want to change the group of all files at path `/mnt/setups/linux`

```
[root@localhost linux]# ll
total 1075560
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      4256 Sep 22 19:19 adobe-release-x86_64-1.0-1.noarch.rpm
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   5255423 Aug 25 07:21 node-v0.10.17-linux-x64.tar.gz
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  13637009 Aug 25 07:17 node-v0.10.17.tar.gz
```

I executed the following command:

```
[root@localhost linux]# chgrp -v admin *
changed group of ‘adobe-release-x86_64-1.0-1.noarch.rpm’ from root to admin
changed group of ‘node-v0.10.17-linux-x64.tar.gz’ from root to admin
changed group of ‘node-v0.10.17.tar.gz’ from root to admin
```

But, the group still remains as `root`

```
[root@localhost linux]# ll
total 1075560
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      4256 Sep 22 19:19 adobe-release-x86_64-1.0-1.noarch.rpm
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   5255423 Aug 25 07:21 node-v0.10.17-linux-x64.tar.gz
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  13637009 Aug 25 07:17 node-v0.10.17.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resolved the problem perfectly:

```
/dev/sda1       /mnt/media      ntfs-3g gid=admin,umask=0022    0 0
/dev/sda5       /mnt/setups     ntfs-3g gid=admin,umask=0022    0 0
/dev/sda6       /mnt/documents      ntfs-3g gid=admin,umask=0022    0 0
```

Answer (score 3):

For each file a filesystem stores the *content* of the file and additional various meta-information. One such information is usually the *name* of the file, another one is usually some kind of *permission*. Different types of filesystem store different information for its files.

UNIX/Linux-Systems (for example in a [ext4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) FS) usually use the traditional POSIX permissions you are talking of. However [NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) stores permissions in the form of more general ACLs.

You tried to change POSIX permission on a NTFS filesytem. As such a filesystem does not support this kind of permission this will fail.

However you can specify what kind of permission you want to have while mounting the filesystem. For the normal ntfs driver `man mount` says:

```
Mount options for ntfs
   [...]   
   uid=value, gid=value and umask=value
          Set  the  file permission on the filesystem.  The umask value is
          given in octal.  By default, the files are owned by root and not
          readable by somebody else.
```

(Those option can be added in fstab in the options field, which currently contains only "defaults".)

You are using the ntfs-3g driver, which should also be able to use these options, but is also very [configurable](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/ownership-and-permissions/).

Comment: Thanks.. based on your answer, I made chagnes in /etc/fstab and it worked.. I've posted the changes as my answer. I feel that should be accepted as the answer as it is exactly what needs to be done. (I can't accept till 2 more days)